# Нужна ли запятая перед или?

Tags: запятая

Каждый из них включает два новых оттенка: белоснежный Ice Vapor и изумрудный Frosted Glen или мерцающий зеленый Serene Green и гранатовый Scarlet Letter.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна, конечно, ведь союз "или" соединяет две пары однородных членов, связанных союзами "и"